# How to display Balloon-tip text in System tray in java

Tags: java, timer, intervals, balloon-tip

Hie Friends.

I am developing an JAVA application which require that Balloon-Tip Text should be show at regular interval of 1 hour.

I am trying for that but don't know how to use Balloon-tip text please any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

### My code is:

```
public void timer_clock()
{   
    theChronometer = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener()
    {
        int seconds,days,hours,min,sec;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            seconds = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()-watchStart)/1000;

            days = seconds / 86400;
    hours = (seconds / 3600) - (days * 24);
    min = (seconds / 60) - (days * 1440) - (hours * 60);
    sec = seconds % 60;

            String s=new String("" + String.format("%02d", hours) + ":"+ String.format("%02d", min) + ":"+ String.format("%02d", sec));

        label.setText(s);

            label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 34));

            switch(s)
            {
                case "00:00:01":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);

                    break;
                case "01:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "02:00:00":
                   trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                   break;
                case "03:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "04:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "05:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;    
                case "06:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "07:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "08:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "09:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "10:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "11:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;    
                case "12:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;    
                 case "13:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "14:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "15:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "16:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "17:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;    
                case "18:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;    
                 case "19:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "20:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "21:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "22:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;
                case "23:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;    
                case "24:00:00":
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Soul Spotter", "\nYour Total WorkTime Is: \n\n"+s , TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    break;    
            }
        }

        private int length(String toString) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    });
    timer_started();
}
public void timer_started()
{
    watchStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    theChronometer.start();
}
```

please tell me what to write in switch case items.
(I had solved this by above code which is edited)
Thanks

Comment: Try taking a look at [How to Use the System Tray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)

Comment: I had minimise the Application at system tray already.!

Comment: I think you misunderstand the difference between "tray" and "bar".  If you've already created a `TrayIcon`, then you just need to display a message, read the linked tutorial to understand more.  If you've already done, this, then you need to update you question with that information...